# Can't style custom menu

Tags: menus, css

I have a Wordpress menu [on my site](http://steven.doig.com.au/) generated by code:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-primary' ) ); ?>
```

When I assign the menu called "Categories" to the "Primary Menu" location, this generates front end code of:

```
<ul id="menu-categories" class="nav-primary">
    <li id="menu-item-910" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-910">
        <a href="http://steven.doig.com.au/category/environmental/">Environmental</a></li>
</ul>
```

The following CSS is not being applied:

```
.nav-primary {
    display: block;
}
.nav-primary ul {
    list-style-type: none !important;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25) !important;
    padding: 5px !important;
    border-radius: 8px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px !important;
}
.nav-primary ul li {
    display: inline-block !important;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25) !important;
    margin-right: 5px !important;
    height: 32px !important;
    padding-top: 8px !important;
    border-radius: 8px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px !important;
}
.nav-primary ul li a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    margin: 8px 14px 0 14px !important;
}
```

How do I style this menu when the ID being output on the front end is generated from the name of the menu in Appearance > Menus ?

If I deploy this theme to the public, I will never be able to anticipate what the name of the menu will be, and the generated ID will always take precedence over the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not targeting the element correctly. Try this:

```
    #mainmenu {
        display: block;
    }
    #mainmenu ul.nav-primary {
        list-style-type: none !important;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25) !important;
        padding: 5px !important;
        border-radius: 8px !important;
        -moz-border-radius: 8px !important;
        -webkit-border-radius: 8px !important;
    }
    #mainmenu ul.nav-primary li {
        display: inline-block !important;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25) !important;
        margin-right: 5px !important;
        height: 32px !important;
        padding-top: 8px !important;
        border-radius: 8px !important;
        -moz-border-radius: 8px !important;
        -webkit-border-radius: 8px !important;
    }
    #mainmenu ul.nav-primary li a {
        text-decoration: none !important;
        color: #fff !important;
        margin: 8px 14px 0 14px !important;
    }
```

Try replacing the code you've mentioned above or adding it at the bottom of file ↓

```
http://steven.doig.com.au/wp-content/themes/transparent/style.css
```

Comment: Getting closer, I think, but still no change.

Comment: That should have fixed it. I tried in firebug and styling of your navigation doesn't look broken anymore. Check it out → http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=vgpu03&s=5

Comment: I've cleared my cache and it remains the same.  Can you try loading the page without custom code in firebug?  I guess you could then determine what CSS code is missing, by building back up to the solution.  (I can't see what is missing from the CSS code I added from your solution.)

Comment: I see. Had a look at the code you've added again and there are some mistakes.

For example:
`#mainmenu ul.nav-primary ul { }`
needs to be:
 `#mainmenu ul.nav-primary { }`

If you just copy and use the code I've given above, it'll work. Doesn't need any editing or adjustments.

Comment: Hi vDog.  This problem has [arisen again](http://tester.doig.com.au/).  The menu UL is given and ID=menu-menuname, and this causes the CSS to drop out.  How do I fix this?